# Serving CADRG (RPF) map images with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I have a large collection of Vietnam CADRG 1:50,000 maps I would like to make available online to Vietnam Veterans and others.  Is there a way to serve them up using OpenLayers?
I have converted a small portion of them to .png tiles using QGIS, however the image quality suffered.
Thank you
Bill

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution would be to use a map server to serve the images as a web service. Then, you can visualize the information using a Web map application that consumes
the publish service.

You already pick OpenLayers as the client geographic library for your Web map application. For the map server, and continuing with open source, you have some choices like [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) and [MapServer](https://mapserver.org).

I am not sure what type of images you have, but I am guessing that are aerials photos. If that is the case, you could create a map with all the images and publish the map as a [WMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Service) service. The standard service for map images.

Comment: thank you.  the CADRG is in RPF format...the tiles are individually compressed using a non-standard asymetrical vector quantization compression scheme, and decompressed by rpf viewers (gdal includes one that is used in QGIS).  I have been able to serve them using geoserver with the gdal package installed, however if i use qgis to create jpeg tiles, the resolution (which is not that good to start with) takes a hit.  i was hoping to find a user that has already implemented a way to directly access the cadrg files using openlayers.

Comment: I see .. Even if you find someway to load the images directly using OL, how do you plan to map the images to the map?

Comment: probably use your suggestion and use a wms service with geoserver.   i would like users to be able to just open their browser to view them rather than use a dedicated client app like openmap or other.